# What does this signify ? Why is Parvathy called both - Gauri as well as Kaali?

Tags: shakti, parvati

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bojkop0fZ6c) in the video,the character of Parvathy is saying is she is both Karma and well Moksha.
She is Light as well as darkness , that she is way as well as the destination . She is begining as well as the end.

That She is both Gauri (the fair woman) as well as Kaali ( the black woman).

**I think it is very intriguing that name of Parvathy is both Gauri as well as Kaali .**

What does it signify ?

Comment: Parvati's complexion was as dark as a blue lotus at birth. Howeven, when Bhagavana Shiva jokingly remarked that when She embraced Him, it appeared like a black snake climbing over a sandal tree & addressed Her as Kāli in front of the fair Urvashi, She was extremely offended. By propitiating Brahma, Parvati cast off her dark skin & became as fair as autumn clouds & lightning, becoming renowned as Gauri. From the discarded dark skin arose Matangi, who in turn gave rise to Kauśiki & Kālikā to kill Śumbha-Niśumbha, who were cursed by Bhagavana Shiva to be slain through Parvati.

Answer (score 1):

It signifies that nearly all Goddesses are aspects of Parvati.

> Pārvatī is the power and consort of Śiva, the god of disintegration
> and destruction. **An overwhelming majority of the goddesses of Hinduism
> are aspects and variations of Pārvatī.** The names by which she is known
> or worshipped are too numerous to mention. If some of the names like
> Pārvatī, Haimavatī, Girijā and Dākṣāyaṇī indicate her origin from the
> Himālayas or Dakṣa (one of the forefathers of mankind), other names
> like Śivā, Mṛḍānī, Rudrāṇī and Śarvāṇi stress her aspect as the spouse
> of Śiva. Still others like Aparṇā and Umā have specific reference to
> certain stories in the paurāṇic literature.
>
> One of the earliest references to this deity is found in the
> Kenopaniṣad (3.12) where she is mentioned as ‘Umā Haima-vatī’
> enlightening Indra, the king of gods, about Brahman, the Absolute or
> God. This reference is enough to conclude that the worship of this
> goddess is very ancient.
>
> ……………………………………………
>
> Like her consort Śiva, she also has two aspects: the mild and the
> terrible. As Pārvatī or Umā she represents the mild aspect. In this
> aspect she is usually shown with Śiva. Then she has only two hands,
> the right hand holding a blue lotus and the left hanging loosely by
> the side. The image is richly decorated. When represented
> independently she is shown with four hands, two hands holding red and
> blue lotuses and the other two exhibiting the varada and abhaya
> mudrās.
>
> Though all the female deities are called Śaktis of their male
> counterparts, the words ‘Śakti’ and ‘Devī’ are more particularly—or
> even exclusively—used to denote the Śakti of Śiva, the innumerable
> aspects of Pārvatī. Considering Śiva as Mahādeva, the Supreme God,
> Pārvatī represents his power by which the universe is created,
> sustained and destroyed.
>
> The Himālayas represent the Ākāśa or ether, the first fundamental
> substance. Menā stands for intelligence. Hence Pārvatī, their
> offspring, represents the conscious substance of the universe. That is
> why she is also called Umā (= light, the bright one).
>
> At the subjective level, Umā-Haima-vatī represents Brahmavidyā or
> spiritual wisdom, by which union with Śiva or God is attained.
>
> Being the consort of Śiva, who is Rudra, the terrible, she also has
> her terrible aspects which need a separate study. ………………….

**A concise Encyclopedia of Hinduism by Swami Harshananda**